# Storing table elements from webpage in dictionary

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract a table from a webpage that I'm working on to store the headers as keys and the body as values but separately to denote which page they're from. Here's what I have tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
s=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.google.com')


all_data = []
for i in range(1,6):
    url = "https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/silvio-adzic/profil/spieler/{}".format(i)
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(3)
    data = {}
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html5lib')
    print(f"In Page {i}")
    for th in soup.select("#yw2 tr"):
        data[th.get_text(strip = True)] = th.find_next('td').get_text(strip=True)
    all_data.append(data)
```

However this produces a jumbled dictionary:

```
[{'competitionwettbewerb': 'Total :',
  'Total :25169524616.948': 'Total :',
  'Regionalliga Süd': 'Regionalliga Süd',
  'Regionalliga Süd7922-2876.318': '',
  '2. Bundesliga': '2. Bundesliga',
  '2. Bundesliga60933873.487': '',
  'RL West-Südwest': 'RL West-Südwest',
  'RL West-Südwest5818-1943.493': '',
  'Oberliga Südwest': 'Oberliga Südwest',
  'Oberliga Südwest2015-1101.649': '',
  'Bundesliga': 'Bundesliga',
  'Bundesliga1212355355': '',
..
..
..
```

(Expected outcome) is there a way to separate these for each page that's extracted so something like this?

```
[{'p1':{'competition': ["Regionalliga Süd", "2. Bundesliga", ...],
'Appearances': [79, 60,...],
'Goals':[22, 9,...],
'Assists':[-, 3, ...]
...},
'p2':{'competition': ["Bundesliga", "2. Bundesliga", ...],
'Appearances': [262, 98,...],
'Goals':[62, 18,...],
'Assists':[79, -, ...]
...}}]
```

Comment: you expect too much. If you want expected result then you will have to write more complex code and work with every row in table separatelly. And it may need also work with every cell in row separatelly because one cell you have to add to `p1` and other cell to `p2`.

Comment: your mind problem is that you read row by row - so you get data in rows - but in results you expect values from columns. And this need to first create dictionares `Appearances`, `Goals`, etc. and later read cells in row and every cell put in different dictionary.

Comment: first you should create `data = {'competition': [], 'Appearances': [], }`, next you should put correct cells in correct places in `data` and finally you should `all_data.append( {'p{}'.format(i): data} )`

Answer (score 0):

This needs more complex code to work with every row and every cell separatelly.

First I create place for all data

```
data = {'competition': [], 'Appearances': [], 'Goals':[], 'Assists':[]}
```

Next I use `for`-loop to get rows in table.
But there are two problems:

- some `tr` are empty but they don't have `class` so it is easy to skip them. I use also `tbody` to skip row in header.
- on some pages it uses ID `yw2` and on other `yw1` but both are in `div` with `data-viewport=Leistungsdaten_Saison` so it is easy to get correct tables.

```
for tr in soup.select("div[data-viewport=Leistungsdaten_Saison] tbody tr[class]"):
```

Next I get all cells in row and put values in correct lists.

```
        cells = tr.find_all('td')
        #print(cells)
        data['competition'].append(cells[1].get_text(strip=True))
        data['Appearances'].append(cells[2].get_text(strip=True))
        data['Goals']      .append(cells[3].get_text(strip=True))
        data['Assists']    .append(cells[4].get_text(strip=True))
```

And finally I put `data` in `all_data` with key `p1`, `p2`, etc.

```
        all_data.append({'p{}'.format(i): data})
```

---

Full working code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.maximize_window()

all_data = []

for i in range(1, 6):
    print('--- page', i, '---')
    
    url = "https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/silvio-adzic/profil/spieler/{}".format(i)
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html5lib')
    
    data = {'competition': [], 'Appearances': [], 'Goals':[], 'Assists':[]}
        
    for tr in soup.select("div[data-viewport=Leistungsdaten_Saison] tbody tr[class]"):
        cells = tr.find_all('td')
        #print(cells)
        data['competition'].append(cells[1].get_text(strip=True))
        data['Appearances'].append(cells[2].get_text(strip=True))
        data['Goals']      .append(cells[3].get_text(strip=True))
        data['Assists']    .append(cells[4].get_text(strip=True))
                                   
    all_data.append({'p{}'.format(i): data})

# --- display ---

for player in all_data:
    name, data = list(player.items())[0]
    print('---', name, '---')
    for key, value in data.items():
        print(key, value)
```

Result:

```
--- p1 ---
competition ['Regionalliga Süd', '2. Bundesliga', 'RL West-Südwest', 'Oberliga Südwest', 'Bundesliga', 'NOFV-Oberliga Süd', 'Oberliga Bayern', 'DFB-Pokal', 'UEFA Cup']
Appearances ['79', '60', '58', '20', '12', '9', '6', '6', '1']
Goals ['22', '9', '18', '15', '1', '-', '2', '2', '-']
Assists ['-', '3', '-', '-', '2', '-', '-', '-', '-']
--- p2 ---
competition ['Bundesliga', '2. Bundesliga', 'DFB-Pokal', 'Champions League', '2. BL North', 'UEFA Cup', 'VL Südwest', '2. BL Nord Aufstiegsr.', 'Ligapokal', "Cup Winners' Cup", 'DFB-SuperCup', 'UI Cup', 'Champions League Qu.', 'Südwestpokal', 'Intertoto-Cup (until 94/95)']
Appearances ['262', '98', '38', '23', '21', '15', '11', '9', '6', '4', '2', '2', '1', '1', '0']
Goals ['62', '18', '9', '7', '3', '4', '1', '2', '2', '2', '-', '2', '-', '1', '-']
Assists ['79', '-', '5', '3', '-', '5', '-', '-', '-', '1', '2', '-', '-', '-', '-']
# ...
```